# C++ Save pointer of object created in function

Tags: c++, pointers, object, memory

I have struct called Rectangle:

```
 struct Rectangle {
    std::vector<float> m_min;
    std::vector<float> m_max;
    exType timeOfArrival, timeOfexpiry;
    unsigned int id;
};
```

In a function I pass a rectangle by value and save the object into a DB. I want to return the pointer of the rectangle so that I can use it out of the function and save it (the pointer) in a vector. From what I have read as of C++11 there is no need to return a pointer so I return the rectangle. Is this the right way? How can I have the pointer to the object created in the function?

This is how I do it now:

```
Rectangle Insert(Rectangle rect){// "Insert" is a function of another class
    SaveIntoToDB(rect);// Calls other functions that use reference
    return rect;
}
```

I need something fast that does not create duplicates in memory.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking for.  It would seem `rect` exists before the function call - so why is there a need to return it.  Also, does SaveIntoDB modify `rect`?

Comment: Well I have a huge file that does not fit into the memory so I read a number of rectangles and store them into the DB. No the SaveIntoDB does not modify the rect.

Comment: See Roddy's code snippet below which pretty much does what you want.

Comment: Since `rect` came from the caller, why do you need to return it back to him? He already has it in his variable that he used during the call.

Answer (score 1):

What would be wrong with this?

```
void Insert(const Rectangle &rect)
{
 ...
}
```

Called like

```
Rect myrect = something...;
Insert(myrect);
doSomething(&myrect);  // Do something with pointer to myrect
```

Generally, based on your question and code, you should be avoiding pointers completely at this stage.

Comment: Well the rectangles do not fit in the memory (billions) so I use a library that Inserts them into a DB. I thought of using only the objects created from the function of DB to manipulate them.

Comment: @TheShadow So you want to store billions of some unique value identifying specific objects in your database? A "pointer" can only point to memory, not a database. If